# Strip PHP tags preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to remove all php tags from a external text so it can be included in php safely.

this is the sample input:

```
<?
?>
<html>
<?php ?>
<?= ?>
</html>
<?
```

or any other possibilites

and output:

```
<html>
</html>
```

the last php open tag may not have an end tag!

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: $text = preg_replace('@\<\?(.*)@is', '', $text);

Comment: I'd add that to the question if I were you.

Comment: @Ali - that regex won't remove each PHP tag separately (it will remove everything after the start of the first PHP tag).

Comment: I know it's not the answer. That was what i've tried! :))

Comment: I think this is a useful thing, but I couldn't find anything googling it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to not include it, but instead load it as a string, using `file_get_contents()`.  That will preserve the PHP tags without executing them.  However, the following regex will do exactly what you asked for:

```
#<\?.*?(\?>|$)#s
```

Here's a breakdown of what that string represents:

```
#       A delimiter marking the beginning and end of the expression - nearly anything will do (preferably something not in the regex itself)
<\?      Find the text "<?", which is the beginning of a PHP tag.  Note that a backslash before the question mark is needed because question marks normally do something special in regular expressions.
.*?     Include as much text as necessary (".*"), but as little as possible ("?").
(\?>|$)  Stop at an ending PHP tag ("?>"), OR the end of the text ("$").  This doesn't necessarily have to stop at the first one, but since the previous part is "as little as possible", it will.
#       The same delimiter, marking the end of the expression
s       A special flag, indicating that the pattern can span multiple lines.  Without it, the regex would expect to find the entire PHP tag (beginning and end) on a single line.
```

Comment: I add some php tags to it so it must be evaluted.

Comment: Perhaps you could execute that extra PHP separately, and insert its results into the text instead?

Comment: I use it as a templating engine. I convert some parts of it to php, but I don't want user to add his code.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a great way to do exactly what you want, but if it's acceptable to send the PHP tags (unparsed) in the output you can just use:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('input.html'); ?>
```

Otherwise, maybe have a look at the token_get_all method:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php

You could iterate over all results and only return those of type T_INLINE_HTML:

```
$toks = token_get_all( file_get_contents( 'input.html' ) );
foreach( $toks as $tok ) {
  if( $tok[0] == T_INLINE_HTML )   {
    print $tok[1];
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't use file_get_contents because I put some php script myself as it's used for a templating engine.